# Copying file from one folder to another in an OS independent way

Tags: java, io

I have tow folders, say folder1 and folder2.

folder1 contains files of different type like .txt, .doc, .png. All file are posted in this folder only.

Now, what i want to do is as soon as file is saved in folder1, a copy of that file goes into subfolder in folder2 and the subfolder name should be the extension of that file. i.e if abc.txt file is saved in folder1 then txt folder should be created inside folder2 (if txt folder does not exist) and abc.txt should be copied inside that subfolder. And if we have xyz.doc file then create doc folder and save inside that. I want to do this in Java.
and this should be platform independent i.e we can copy in Window, Linux or Android.

Comment: Ok, so we get it.  What is the problem you are facing doing this?

Comment: So where exactly are you having problems? What did you try? The hardest part is probably getting the notification when some file is saved in `folder1`.

Comment: my main problem is making it platform independent. i.e how can i make it to work in android,linux,window...... i dont have any idea how to approach this part....

Comment: and how to know a new file is added to the folder1 (i think that i can do by rechecking the folder after few min or so.... ).

Comment: Also note that detection new files is **not** the same as detecting when a new file has been written completely by an external process. The latter is even harder.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this one by [`File.list()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) & [Common's FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can start a thread that checks frequently for new files in that folder. The thread has a list of all hashes from the files. If the file is not in the list its a new file. Then you can copy the file to the new location. Instead of checking the name of a file you can check the hash.

Comment: *"If the file is not in the list its a new file."  It might be one of the existing `File` instances, renamed.

Comment: Then he can generate a hash from the files and save the hashes in the list.

Comment: Excellent idea!  Please edit that into your answer so I can delete my comment & up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wait for Java 7?  [WatchService](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) is perfect for notification of new `File` objects.

Quote from the top of those JavaDocs:

> A watch service that *watches* registered objects for changes and events. For example a file manager may use a watch service to **monitor a directory for changes** so that it can update its display of the list of files when **files are created or deleted.**

( *Emphasis* by Oracle, **boldness** by me. ;)

Comment: This will not work on Android. While it's loosely based on Java SE, it's based on Java 6 and I don't know their time table for "updating" that.